# Rollback performs clear form in Oracle Forms

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I have put Rollback command in a button , whenever i click the button data has rolling back also it clears the form data. Suggest any, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**`CLEAR_FORM`** is the inteded action on Rollback, some used **`ISSUE_ROLLBACK(null)`** to avoid it, but it is not recommended, see [Oracle Community](https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/651198/difference-between-rollback-and-issue-rollback-null)